# Classmate is being deported - how could I politely offer to buy their furniture?

Tags: conflict-aversion, requests

My classmate is being deported from the U.S. due to visa issues and has no intentions of returning in the coming years - they plan to join a lab at university in their home country.  They're really upset about having to leave and are easily angered about anything so I try to be careful with my words for them.

I know they have some furniture that I could use.  Since they'll soon have no use for it, how could I ask for it? I could offer money too but not much; my stipend is not much to live on.

Ideally I'd inherit their furniture.  Their family in their home country is wealthy, so I could potentially get free furniture that I've needed for a while now.

Comment: Hello network visitors! Please note that IPS is fairly strict about [using comments as intended](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). **Comments are *only* for clarifying and improving the question.** Partial answers or general thoughts about the situation may be deleted without notice. If you'd like to write an answer, make sure to check out our posts on [How do I write a good answer?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/) and [citation expectations](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/) first. Thanks!

Answer (score 74):

In my experience, offering to help them with the problem is the best way to start.

“What’s your plan for moving? Do you need help?”

This opens the door for you to be able to then offer to take the furniture off their hands to be helpful.

I have moved a lot and it’s a pain, even when it’s not in bad circumstances. Your friend might be relieved to have a plan for it and may not ask for money.

Comment: Just as an aside, "Is there anything I can do to help?" is the best starting point when dealing with anyone having trouble.

Comment: I find "Is there anything I can do to help?" better than "Do you need help?”. In the latter sentence, *need* has a subconscious meaning of "Only bother me if you absolutely can't do it alone". (That said, when speaking I get it wrong and use "need" myself all the time...)

Answer (score 38):

It seems OP does not have genuine concern for the wellbeing of the deported. That's alright, we don't have to be close friends of everyone. But let's not try to act like we are close friends just to inherit the furniture, as some answers here suggest. That's underhanded, deceptive and once the target person recognizes this, they will certainly be very disappointed or angry.

I would ask the person directly, something like:

> Hey, I hear you are forced to leave the country. I'm sorry this is happening to you. If it helps at all, I've long searched for furniture, and since yours may be left behind, I feel we could both benefit if you decide to sell it to me. I would also like to help you with moving in return.

- Being sorry is a mere display of basic empathy. It is not underhanded.
- The benefit is clear: They do not have to worry about getting rid of the furniture, so that can be helpful.
- Offering some additional help is a guesture that shows you are not preying on defenseless panicking victims, but are willing to do a fair trade.

I've been in more or less similar situations and have experienced both approaches. Tho the reasoning above should provide more plausibility. In my experience, just stating, in a friendly manner, your intention is virtually always better.

[I grew up in Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/38177/971), but I believe that it is possible to be both polite *and* direct.

Comment: Isn't being sorry a display of sympathy rather than empathy?

Comment: Could you explain the apparently large difference you see between your advice of "display basic empathy, even if you are not genuinely concerned" and "bla bla bla, empathize"?

Comment: @smcs "bla bla bla" implies (strongly, to me) that no genuine concern is needed at all, that the action is entirely focussed on the goal of acquiring a financial benefit and not on helping a fellow human in trouble. That abusing the pressure is fine. I see this in contrast with a true mutual benefit, which includes a basic level of just trying to be helpful. The spirit of the question (to the target person) is different.

Comment: Hi mafu, welcome to IPS. Answers here [need to include backup](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3271/3171) in the form of either personal experience or references - could you [edit] to add that? While you've included your reasoning here, can you add whether that's based on your own observations of a similar situation, or something you learned elsewhere?

Comment: @gerrit you generally have to have been empathetic before you can truly be sympathetic. Otherwise you're offering fake condolences in your sympathy. But getting caught up on those semantics is silly, especially with someone who most likely isn't a native speaker. (assumption as they grew up in Germany, not from their well written English)

Comment: In British English, there is almost no way to ask somebody "would you like to sell me your furniture" that doesn't actually mean "would you like to give me your furniture for free" (which is what the OP really wants, of course). And in the UK there are plenty of second-hand furniture dealers (including charitable organizations) who will pay the classmate a *fair* price for it.

Comment: @alephzero In my experience charity shops usually *receive* furniture for free and *sell* it for a small amount of money, which is how they finance that they also give away some furniture to those who really need it and can't afford to buy any.  I was happy to give furniture to charity shops because they came to pick it up, so unless I could find someone to buy it and pick it up, it was the only way to get rid of it for free at all.

Comment: @gerrit - I worked for one. We refused to pick up some things - stained mattresses, plywood wardrobes, sideboards of any type, dismantled flatpack, etc, sometimes to the annoyance of the 'generous' aspiring donors.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I understand, charity shops are not a "free furniture disposal" service, and I did not mean to suggest they are!  But if furniture is good enough that OP wants to pay for it then it *may* be good enough for a charity shop to receive (or not, I don't know the exact standards).

Comment: This seems like a good approach. If you want to really make sure you're straightforward, you can cut out the "sorry" and "help" part, and just say "Hey I know it's awkward, but I hope you don't mind me asking: would you consider selling your furntiure?"

Comment: @gerrit - we ran a big shop in a former warehouse; we knew, from experience, what our customers, paying or not, wanted and what they did not want. They did not want luxury, but they wanted, and we supported this, things to be clean and serviceable. When we turned down monstrous deal wardrobes or mattresses with stains in the middle region, the would-be donors sometimes angrily asked if 'the poor were getting fussy'.

Comment: American here - in this particular context, I would agree; offering to help with the ulterior motive of getting furniture and not out of genuine concern would be quite off-putting. If you want to leave a gesture of good-will because you were on good terms, you might also offer help but save it for after you've made your intentions clear. That way, your gesture is not interpreted as deceitful.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would say that I am so so so sorry that he needs to leave and ask many questions about family and future plans, and say how much regret, and would spontaneously mention the books:

> what are you going to do with your furniture? Maybe you should sell it or even give it as a gift. I am so sorry. Please remember me if you decide to do so.

When my mother's friend passed away, it was very sad for everyone but at the end, they gifted us their furniture. They did know we are in need and wanted to help us.

Maybe if you let them know how much that would be important to you, they will offer it themselves.